# Is there a missing episode season 3 of Farscape which was referenced in season 4?

Tags: farscape

I am so confused as in Season 4 Episode 2 of Farscape they have the usual, "Previously on..." flashbacks, and in that there is a flashback to a scene after the command carrier has been destroyed and Scorpius was alive and was being stripped of rank, and Bracca instated in Scorpius's place. But that scene never happened!

And I was thinking about it and I realized that there must have been an episode between the one where the command carrier is destroyed and the finale episode in season 3, because so much of the finale made no sense... Like they talked about rescuing that old lady from a ship and her sticking around after it left; but that never happened, so I assumed she was some weird figment voodoo. But then she is in season 4 ep 3.

Someone please help me; I am so confused!

Comment: Noranti, at least, I think was supposed to be confusing, and the rest of the crew played on the viewer's confusion with none of them knowing her either

Answer (score 3):

From IMDB:
The "Previously on Farscape" sequence features portions of a scene where Braca was promoted by Grayza to the rank of Captain and thus does not accept commands from Scorpius anymore. This scene was filmed for the previous episode "Crichton Kicks" but was deleted from it.

...I know...it hurts...

Comment: Links to sources for this answer?

Comment: IMDB trivia is not particularly reliable

Answer (score 2):

A quick search gives the impression that there was some editing done to "Lambs to a Slaughter," including a scene where the old lady and other prisoners were released before the command carrier was destroyed.

However, a quick search for deleted scenes doesn't provide said scenes, so that could be incorrect.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think they messed up. There are events that glue the coming happenings together which they forgot to in-cooperate in season 3. So they used S4E2 "previously on" to say "oh, by the way: Scorpios is alive, Braca betrayed him and became Captain. and Chiana gave John 'hello' kiss"  ^^;

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.